# What should i write in sql command to select data from 2 tables against one id?

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have two tables, one is tbl_order, and another is tbl_order_details. i want to select data from two tables by order_id. I wrote the following sql command in my model.

```
function select_order_details($order_id){
$sql = "SELECT 
            tbl_order.order_total,
            tbl_order_details.product_name,
            tbl_order.ordered_date,
            tbl_order.order_id
        FROM tbl_order
        INNER JOIN tbl_order_details 
            ON tbl_order.order_id=tbl_order_details.order_id";

$query_result=$this->db->query($sql);
$result=$query_result->result();
return $result;
}
```

then i run a foreach loop in my view file. But i got all the data from those two tables with all order_id. But i want to select data against one order_id which i will pass as a parameter. how can i do that? pls help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could add a where and use codeigniters query binding like so. Code igniter query binding will help prevent SQL injection attacks.

```
function select_order_details($order_id){
$sql = "SELECT 
        tbl_order.order_total,
        tbl_order_details.product_name,
        tbl_order.ordered_date,
        tbl_order.order_id
    FROM tbl_order
    INNER JOIN tbl_order_details 
        ON tbl_order.order_id=tbl_order_details.order_id
        where tbl_order. id = ?;"

$query_result=$this->db->query($sql, $order_id);
$result=$query_result->result();
return $result;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Add a `WHERE` condition to the filter for the `order_id` you are passing to the function, like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT tbl_order.order_total,tbl_order_details.product_name,tbl_order.ordered_date,tbl_order.order_id
FROM tbl_order
INNER JOIN tbl_order_details ON tbl_order.order_id=tbl_order_details.order_id where tbl_order.order_id='"+$order_id+"'";
```

Comment: I would highly recommend against concatenation. Hello SQL injection!